# Converting aspx page into flash swf

Tags: asp.net, flash, adsense

I have a iframe for advertisement but google adsense want to flash format how to convert iframe to flash swf

Answer (score 0):

As Robert posted, [Print2Flash](http://print2flash.com/) will take any printable content (presumably you have some printable content displayed in the iFrame) and convert it to a flash (swf) file. From the Print2Flash website:

> Print2Flash lets you easily convert any printable document (e.g. Microsoft Word, or Excel, or PowerPoint document) to an Adobe ® Flash ® file (**file with SWF extension**). This file can be shared with users who don't have the software that created the original document (for example, Microsoft Word). You can view such files with Adobe ® Flash ® Player that is available across a number of operating systems. And these files can be easily published on the Web as well for fast and easy access to them from anywhere across the globe.